# Get URL data using php $_GET

Tags: php

I have changed the URL using .htaccess file as follows.

https://www.xx.com/Listing/Product/?sku=211&act=edit to https://www.xx.com/Listing/Product/211/edit

using following code:

```
RewriteRule ^Listing/Product/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /Listing/Product/index.php?sku=$1&act=$2 [NC,L]
```

Now I can get sku and act data using php $_GET.

I need to get t1 value in URL https://www.xx.com/Listing/Product/211/edit?t1=555. I can not get t1 data by using php $_GET. How can I get t1 value?

Comment: I do not need to get the same pattern. That is why

Comment: Try adding the [QSA](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteFlags+QSA) flag: `[QSA,NC,L]`